# How to store result of a query in another tables specific column

Tags: mysql, spring-jdbc

Suppose i have two columns T1 and T2, I want to fetch the data from T2 table and store it in a particular column in T1. For e.g:
T1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) and T2(c1,c2,c3). I want to fetch all the data from all the columns in T2 table and save it in T1(c5) column, What should be the data type of column c5 and how to store T2's result in it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)